# How to stream a video in Laravel

Tags: laravel, video-streaming, fopen, laravel-9, laravel-filesystem

I'm trying to stream a video in Laravel 9 by using **imanghafoori1/laravel-video** package.
but I keep getting an error message:

> fopen(C:...\storage\videoFiles/ui/2024-02-11-1-I6bnWsI8J0-128210 (Original).mp4): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I have added the route =>

```
Route::get('/stream/{video}', [VideoController::class, 'stream'])->name('admin.product.video.stream');
```

and the method in controller =>

```
public function stream(Video $video)
    {
      $path = storage_path($video->file_path);
      VideoStreamer::streamFile($path);
    }
```

also the link in my blade =>

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.product.video.stream', $video->id) }}" >play</a>
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: HTTP/Web projects cannot read a file from a users hard drive... **(1)** Try starting the URL path as `file:///C:/` not just as `C:` **(2)** If still failing, then the most guaranteed way is to put the mp4 in same folder as your App, then use its file name only without any extra details (_eg:_ no drive or sub-folders mentioned) **(3)** Put the file online (or use your localhost to load it from your hard drive). **PS:** Do you have XAMPP or similar installed? It allows a folder on your drive to be used as a HTTP location and that's how you can test web projects/code whilst mixing local files.

Comment: PPS: Test an online MP4 link: https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 and see if the error goes away. This will confirm if the rest of your code works okay (and that the local file access part is being the only problem). Secondly use a simple file name for testing, with **no spaces**. Call your C file as `test1.mp4` (not `bnWsI8J0-128210 (Original).mp4` which has spaces etc)

Comment: I can't put the video in the same folder as App. because it's uploaded in storage and I want to read the uploaded file from storage.

Comment: @LaravelLearner how is it uploaded in storage? double check to make sure its in the path you expect

Comment: I solved it by using 
      $path = Storage::path($video->file_path);
to get the correct path. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I used **Storage::path** to access the file_path of my video.
here is the stream function:

```
public function stream(Video $video)
    {
      $path = Storage::path($video->file_path);
      VideoStreamer::streamFile($path);
    }
```